# Как добавить Progress bar при копирование папки с сетевого ресурса?

Tags: c#, progress-bar

Пишу приложение для копирования определённой папки с сетевого ресурса на локальный компьютер после копирования создаётся ярлык, всё работает. Но есть идея сделать что бы при копировании отображался Progress bar и можно было копировать несколько приложений одновременно, прошу помощи в реализации идеи. Мой код ниже

```
public static void RA1112(string begin_dir1, string end_dir1)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\APPS\\RA1112");
    begin_dir1 = "W:\\Program\\DIS\\RS\\RA1112";
    end_dir1 = "C:\\APPS\\RA1112";
    //Берём нашу исходную папку
    DirectoryInfo dir_inf = new DirectoryInfo(begin_dir1);
    //Перебираем все внутренние папки
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dir_inf.GetDirectories())
    {
        //Проверяем - если директории не существует, то создаем;
        if (Directory.Exists(end_dir1 + "C:\\APPS\\RA1112" + dir.Name) != true)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(end_dir1 + "C:\\APPS\\RA1112" + dir.Name);
        }

        //Рекурсия (перебираем вложенные папки и делаем для них то-же самое).
        RA1112(dir.FullName, end_dir1 + "C:\\APPS\\RA1112" + dir.Name);
    }

    //Перебираем файлы в папке источнике.
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(begin_dir1))
    {
        //Определяем (отделяем) имя файла с расширением - без пути (но с слешем "\").
        string filik = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'), file.Length - file.LastIndexOf('\\'));
        //Копируем файл с перезаписью из источника в приёмник.
        File.Copy(file, end_dir1 + "\\" + filik, true);
    }

    var wsh = new WshShell();
    var shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\RA1112.lnk") as IWshShortcut;
    if (shortcut == null) return;

    //   shortcut.Arguments = "c:\\app\\settings1.xml";
    shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\\APPS\\RA1112\\COLVIR.exe";
    // not sure about what this is for
    shortcut.WindowStyle = 1;
    shortcut.Description = "my shortcut description";
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\APPS";
    shortcut.IconLocation = "C:\\APPS\\RA1112\\COLVIR.exe";
    shortcut.Save();
}
```

Comment: Уточните, что именно вы хотите сделать и что именно в этом у вас вызывает затруднения?

Comment: `RA1112` - ужасное название для метода! )

Comment: У меня очень много методов и что бы не путаться назвал так).

Comment: Не получается прикрутить к нему прогрес бар

Comment: Что значит "не получается", телепаты в отпуске, расшифруйте! ) *расшифровку добавьте в тело вопроса

Comment: ну сделайте как [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044629/file-copy-with-progress-bar)

Comment: Мой Вам совет, давайте **осмысленные** названия методам/функциям, для просветления советую обратить внимание например на [Чистый код](http://www.piter.com/product_by_id/26433659)

Comment: Обычно чтобы не путаться методы называют в соответствии с тем, что именно они делают. И знаете ли вы, что методы можно называть на русском?

Comment: @PavelMayorov пробовал я как то поначалу именовать методы/функции русскими именами: да в этом случае дать название проще но сталкиваешься с постоянным переключением языка что вызывает неудобства. поэтому я пытаюсь сформулировать имя метода/функции/переменной английскими словами, в крайнем случае прибегаю к переводчику